# showing a hidden table in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show a hidden table when i click on a button, someone can help, i want to show a table that is always hidden but i want to show it only when i click in the button.

this is the code of button and js:

```
 <a class="nav-item" href="{{url_for('treinar_modelo')}}">
<form action="" method="POST">
<button id="md"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="treinar" name="treinar" >Treinar modelo
  <i style="font-family: FontAwesome !important;" class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
</form>
</a>
</nav>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
 document.getElementById('md').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const scr = document.createElement('score');
  $.post("{{ url_for('treinar_modelo') }}", { score : scr }, function (data) {
    element.textContent = data;
  });
</script>
```

and this is the table code and js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#md").click(function(){
    $('table').show();

});

</script>


<table   style=" text-align: center; align: center; valign: middle; border: 15px solid white; border-top:none; border-bottom:none; opacity : 0.7;
    " class="table table-dark" hidden >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Floresta aleatória</th>
      <th scope="col">Support vector machine</th>
      <th scope="col">Árvore de decisão</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td><output  >  {{  scoref  }}  </output>
      <td><output  >  {{  scoresvm  }}  </output></td>
      <td><output  >  {{  scoret  }}  </output></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Edit your title to not all-caps and spell javascript correctly

Comment: you use two functions to catch click - `addEventListener` and `jQuery`. One function  can block other function. Why don't you do it in only one function.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `});` in your jquery function.

Change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#md").click(function(){
    $('table').show();
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#md").click(function(){
    $('table').show();
  });
});
```

You're also missing a `});` at the end of your `document.getElementById('md').addEventListener('click', function (ev)` call. Then just fix your `$.post` call.

For testing purposes, I replaced `{ score : scr }` with `JSON.stringify({ score : scr })`. And I commented out `element.textContent = data`, due to there is no 
`element` or `data` variables.

That should at least get your table to display.

```html
<nav>
<a class="nav-item" href="{{url_for('treinar_modelo')}}">
<form action="" method="POST">
<button id="md"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="treinar" name="treinar" >Treinar modelo
  <i style="font-family: FontAwesome !important;" class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
</form>
</a>
</nav>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
 document.getElementById('md').addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const scr = document.createElement('score');
  $.post("{{ url_for('treinar_modelo') }}", JSON.stringify({ score : scr }), function (data) {
    //element.textContent = data;
  });
  });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#md").click(function(){
    $('table').show();
});
});

</script>


<table   style=" text-align: center; align: center; valign: middle; border: 15px solid white; border-top:none; border-bottom:none; opacity : 0.7;
    " class="table table-dark" hidden >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Floresta aleatória</th>
      <th scope="col">Support vector machine</th>
      <th scope="col">Árvore de decisão</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td><output  >  {{  scoref  }}  </output></td>
      <td><output  >  {{  scoresvm  }}  </output></td>
      <td><output  >  {{  scoret  }}  </output></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @viniciusreis I added an extra line in my answer that you were missing

Comment: unfortunately not, to be honest i was expecting some suggestion about the function itself, because i am, propositily, using the hidden parameter in my table to hide it, but i want to create a function to show this hidden table just when i click in the button "treinar"

Comment: Which function? And Isn't that what my example is doing? Showing the table when the button is clicked.

Comment: i mean a javascript function, but i think the function i'snt working cause i am using a hidden argument in the table form if u note, but that is propositily, cause i want this table hide until i click in the button to call it, but i think the hidden argument have a bigger priority in the code that even a convencional function can overpass it. i dont know ;(